# How to read documents from Firestore that was added using hashMap in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have managed to add data as `hashMap` into `Firestore` as follows but I have a hard time reading all documents from `Firebase` without a model class.

```
        val itemRequest = hashMapOf(
        "item" to newItem,
        "item_detail" to itemDetails,
        "requested_by" to getCurrentUserID(),
        "timestamp" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    )
    mFireStore.collection("item_request")
            .document()
            .set(itemRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
            fragment.successAddingItemRequest()
        }
            .addOnFailureListener {

            }
```

Comment: Create a model class then. That would be easy to maintain and less error-prone.

Comment: I usually do with model class, in order to reduce the number of the model classes, I thought of doing it this way. I do not know which is better in terms of performance though.

Comment: The code that you are using to add data to Firestore looks really good to me. What have you tried in code to read the data? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DocumentSnapshot.data` property to convert the `DocumentSnapshot` to `Map<String, Any>`.

In your case, you can use:

```kotlin
firestore.collection(collectionId).document(documentId).get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot -> 
        val data = documentSnapshot.data
        val item = data["item"]
        val itemDetails = data["item_detail"]
        ...
    }
```

Here you will have to cast the returned `Any` map value to its appropriate data type.

But a better way to do all this would have been to create a model class for storing data and using `DocumentSnapshot.getObject` to get the data back.